# Clarifications on JSONDecoder when decoding a single value

Tags: swift, decodable, jsondecoder

I was trying to perform some tests on `JSONDecoder` and I've encountered a strange behavior. In particular, when I use the following code an error is thrown.

```
let data = "Sample String".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(String.self, from: data)
    print(decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))

On the contrary if I put a number as string and `Int.self` as the decoding type the value is printed correctly.

```
let data = "100".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(Int.self, from: data)
    print(decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> 100

Any reason why this happens?

Comment: Isn't `"Sample String"`, which is then just `Sample String` is an invalid JSON then. Shouldn't it be `"\"Sample String\""`?

Comment: Unrelated, but you can write `Data("100".utf8)`. it's shorter and avoid the force unwrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `some string` is not valid json, but `"some string"` is.
you need quotes in your string:

`let data = "\"Sample String\"".data(using: .utf8)!`